# The correct way to print a drupal block assigned to a region on node templete in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

What is the correct way to print a drupal block assigned to a region on a node template ex(node.tpl.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [module_invoke($module, $hook)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7) to do so.

> $module: The name of the module (without the .module extension).
>
> $hook: The name of the hook to invoke.

Code snippet:

```
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
print $block['content'];
```

**OR**

use the following code snippet:

```
function block_print_html($module, $block_id)
{
  $block_html = "";
  $block = block_load($module, $block_id);
  $block_content = _block_render_blocks(array($block));
  $block_build = _block_get_renderable_array($block_content);
  return = drupal_render($build);
}
```

Comment: Try not to use the module_invoke() function as it doesn't use the block.tpl.php file and it doesn't print out your header.  Your second function is the better approach.